Laravel pagination issue: Method Collection::links does not exist
I'm encountering an issue with Laravel pagination. Despite my code seeming correct, I'm unable to paginate my news pages to display only 10 per page. The error I receive is:

"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist."

Here is the code in my controller:
namespace App\Http\Controllers\pages;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\admin\Noticia;

class NewsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $news = Noticia::paginate(10);

        return view('pages.news', [
            'news' => $news
        ]);
    }
}

I've also included the necessary code in my AppServiceProvider.php file, where I import Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator; and specify that I'm using Bootstrap-5.
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrapFive();
    }
}

Finally, here's the code in my view, where I call the collection and the links() method to display all the paginations:
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    {{ $news->links() }}
</div>

Despite all this, I'm still encountering the error. Any help would be appreciated.

I haven't used Bootstrap in ages (go Tailwind) but in app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php can you change Paginator::useBootstrapFive(); to Paginator::useBootstrap();. Just in case change Noticia::paginate(10); to Noticia::latest()->paginate(10); in your controller. After your @foreach in the blade view file try {{ $noticias->links() }} OR $noticias->links('pagination::bootstrap-5')

try this Paginator::useBootstrap();
